# How to connect to an AP via terminal (OS X)

Tags: wireless-networking, terminal, osx-yosemite

I've been wondering, but couldn't exactly find any relevant answers on SO or Google, if there was some way that I could connect to a wireless access point via the terminal.  This question is mostly relevant to OS X since I want to change my machine's connected WAP--not just starting a simple SSH or Telnet session.

If this cannot be done (easily?), could you mention some alternatives that could lead to the same effect?

I am currently using OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to connect to a Wi-Fi network using [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(OS_X)), you can use the command `networksetup -setairportnetwork device_name wifi_network password`. If the wifi network is an unsecured one that doesn't require you to know a WPA/WEP key in order to connect, you can omit the password at the end of the command. If you are already connected to a wifi network, the connection will be switched to the one you specify. E.g., you could use the following command if your wireless device is identified by en1 and you were connecting to a network with an [SSID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_(802.11_network)#Service_set_identification_.28SSID.29) of guest with no password:

```
$ networksetup -setairportnetwork en1 guest
```

You can determine which device in the system supports Wi-Fi connections with `networksetup -listallhardwareports`.

See [Using networksetup for Wi-Fi networks on OS X systems](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/networksetup-wifi.php) for other options for using the networksetup command on OS X systems for managing Wi-Fi connections.

Comment: I will check this once I get back from work. Thanks for the answer too :)